# Make a infinite List stack

Tags: java, list, infinite

I want to create a List which has List as its DataType which stacks itself.
Is it possible to create a List with Lists within the other Lists?

Example:

```
List<List<List<List<List<DataType>>>>>
```

But in an "infinite" way?
If possible how?
To list Files

Comment: Do you have a practical use?  I think if you're trying to use it, at some point it will be finite

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Of course, type `List<List<` infinite times. It won't compile because the file will be infinitely long, and you'll need a harddrive with infinite space.

Comment: Given that all machines have a finite amount of resources, there is no way to make an infinite number of `List`.

Comment: Universe is finite, infinite lists don't exist, YouTube muttations of space time continuum

Comment: It sounds to me like you're trying to build some kind of "Tree" structure. Look at creating a `Node` class, which contains a list of all the nodes it's connected to (`List<Node>`). This link might be useful: https://programtalk.com/java/java-tree-implementation/

Comment: The only possible usage for such a list would be my girlfriend's shopping list.

Answer (score 8):

Use self-bounded generics:

```
<T extends List<T>> void whyWouldYouWantToDoThis(T reference) {

}
```

Comment: upvote for method name

Comment: Is it possible to use that?  It looks like you'd need to give it the infinite stack of lists as the input

Comment: Define "use". You can certainly invoke it with `null`.

Comment: Note to OP: don't do this.

Comment: @phflack also, you could invoke it with a raw-typed list.